# Ordered list - style the number on li rollover?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have stylized an ordered list to show a rounded box around the number of the list.  What I am interested in doing is having this box change color when the li is hovered.

See fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CH74M/

```
<ol class="testing">
    <li>Test number 1</li>
    <li>Test number 2</li>
    <li>Test number 3</li>
</ol>


ol.testing {
    counter-reset:li; /* Initiate a counter */
    margin:0 0 0 45px;
}
ol.testing > li {
    position:relative; /* Create a positioning context */
    margin:0 0 30px 2em; /* Give each list item a left margin to make room for the numbers */
    padding:3px 8px; /* Add some spacing around the content */
    list-style:none; /* Disable the normal item numbering */
}
ol.testing > li:before {
    content:counter(li); /* Use the counter as content */
    counter-increment:li; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
    /* Position and style the number */
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:-2em;
    font-size:15px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    width:2em;
    /* Some space between the number and the content in browsers that support
   generated content but not positioning it (Camino 2 is one example) */
    margin-right:8px;
    padding:4px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#2363a1;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With :hover before :before you can do it

```
ol.testing > li:hover:before {
  color: #090;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ifeyaw/1/

Comment: Hah, I swear I tried that.  I must have had before:hover lol  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to do this when the a link inside the li is hovered as well?

Comment: @user756659 Great, glad it works very well, did you mean something like this http://jsbin.com/ifeyaw/4

Comment: I think I worded that bad as I was tired... I meant the rollover would work when hovered over the a link instead of the entire li.

Comment: Yes I understand but I thought that would work for you, Check this instead, here we worked on the a link instead of li http://jsbin.com/udunoh/1/

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by

```
ol li:hover:before { 
   color: red; 
}
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Answer (score 0):

Just added this bit to the code

```
ol.testing > li:hover:before {
    background:#000000;
}
```

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/CH74M/1/

I'm not sure which browsers you want to support, but based on http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html before is only available on everything ie8 and up, and so is hover so that shouldn't be a problem